# Can a hacker spoof any IP address of his choice?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, routes

For example.

Lets say we have the following linux server:

```
host-server: 54.215.128.59
```

This servers will only accept connections from the following ip : 159.65.32.123

If a hacker only knows this information.

Could he be able to trick the host-server that the conection is coming from 159.65.32.123?

This way he would be jumping any firewall established.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't very likely. Nothing is stopping you from defining you own IP address to whatever you want. In linux you can do it with (assuming you network interface is `eth0`):

`sudo ifconfig eth0 159.65.32.123/24`

If you are behind a NAT then you'll have to change its address and not yours. However, [ISPs should have anti-spoofing](https://www.manrs.org/isps/guide/antispoofing/) measures in place that block packets with an IP address they didn't assign you.

There is also the problem of the return path. When the server will want to send something to this address, the packet will be routed according to the routing rules of all the nodes in the way, which are unlikely to point to the hacker's ISP.

If you are on a LAN with the server then it should be more possible, though you will likely need to handle the collision of IP addresses, and the problem of spoofing IP addresses on a different subnet. One option is to use ARP poisoning and do a MitM between the server and the router.

Comment: The point about ISPs using anti-spoofing is a bit weak, you can't ever assume that.  You'd need to have vetted every ISP in the entire world.  Worse, proximity is a factor.  You've identified that a hacker on the LAN may be dangerous, but what about in a different office on the same street with the same ISP?  An ISP may not have anti spoofing at every level of their network, so simply being on the same ISP might be enough.